# Adding 'For Loop' instead of 'forEach'

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

**This:**

```
function hideAllButtons(button) {
  button.querySelectorAll(".play, .pause, .speaker").forEach(hide);
}
```

**Is changed to this:**

https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/95/

```
  function hideAllButtons(button) {
    const buttons = button.querySelectorAll(".play, .pause, .speaker");
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
      hide(buttons[i]);
    }
  }
```

How would I add **For Loop** to this code?

```
  function hideAllButtons(button) {
    const buttonSelectors = ".play, .pause, .speaker";
    button.querySelectorAll(buttonSelectors).forEach(hide);
  }
```

**I got up this far:**

```
function hideAllButtons(button) {
  const buttonSelectors = ".play, .pause, .speaker";
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
    hide(buttons[i]);
  }
}
```

**Where would this go?**

```
(buttonSelectors)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve/can't achieve? 
Your `buttonSelectors` is just the string selector, apply the selection like so : 

`const buttons = button.querySelectorAll(buttonSelectors)` 

And it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `button` argument to the function is not used.
- There's really no value to creating a variable that only gets used
  once, so eliminate the `buttonSelectors` constant and just get all
  the buttons.
- (FYI), `.forEach()` doesn't work in all browsers on node lists, so if
  you do use it, convert the node list to an array first and call
  `.forEach()` on the array. Here's an example of how to do that:

  `let btnArray = 
     Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".play, .pause, .speaker"));
  btnArray.forEach(. . .)`

So, for your question:

```
function hideAllButtons() {

  // Get the buttons node list
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".play, .pause, .speaker");

  // Loop over them
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    hide(buttons[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to use this how would it get added on? (buttonSelector) Can you show an example?

Comment: "convert the node list to an array first and call .forEach() on the array." Can you show an example of how this would be done?

Comment: @MaryElliot `let btnArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".play, .pause, .speaker"));`

Comment: How would I add Array to this code? function pauseAllButtons() {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".playButton");
    buttons.forEach(function hidePause(button) {
      if (isPlaying(button)) {
        showPlayButton(button);
      }
    });
  }   https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/103/

Comment: @MaryElliot I've already shown you that. Pass your `document.querySelector()` code into `Array.prototype.slice.call()` and the result will be an array.

Comment: I think I got it here:      function pauseAllButtons() {
      let btnArray =
        Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".playButton"));
      btnArray.forEach(function hidePause(button) {
        if (isPlaying(button)) {
          showPlayButton(button);
        }
      });
    }   https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/107/

Comment: @MaryElliot Yes. That's correct. Now, you can safely use `.forEach()` in any browser that supports it, regardless of whether it's supported on a node list or not.

Comment: What if I set it up like this instead, is that good, or not?      function pauseAllButtons() {
      const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".playButton")
      Array.from(buttons)
        .filter(isPlaying)
        .forEach(showPlayButton)
    }   https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/111/

Comment: @MaryElliot No. Because `Array.from()` is not supported in the same browsers that don't support `.forEach` on a node list. Use the technique I've shown.

Comment: @MaryElliot Please up vote all helpful answers and consider marking mine as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-right of it.

Comment: I did, it!!!!!! What did I do wrong here? Before adding let https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/118/, After - https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/117/ It's all messed up now.

Comment: Why "let buttons" and not "const buttons"? What's the difference?

Comment: This code uses: (btnArray) https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/146/ / This code uses: (No Array) https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/148/ How would I fix the code that uses (btnArray) ?

Comment: @MaryElliot Your comment doesn't describe what your problem is.  If you have a new problem, please post a new question.

Comment: The code you made made all the playbuttons disappear. https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/146/ After you click on any playbutton, they all disappear. Click on any of them, and they all disappear. This is the one that uses this:  (btnArray)

Comment: @MaryElliot Your question asked how to loop over all `.play`, `.pause`, and `.speaker` buttons and call a function called `hide` that is passed each button found. That's what my answer shows. So, it seems that the code is doing exactly what you asked for. I think you should re-examine your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function hideAllButtons(button) {
    const buttonSelectors = ".play, .pause, .speaker";
    const buttons = button.querySelectorAll(buttonSelectors);
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
      hide(buttons[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This one doesn't use a let?

Comment: @MaryElliot `let` isn't a requirement for variable declaration. It provides block-level scoping for your variable, but that's not always necessary. It's a good general idea to use `let`, but not required.

Comment: Doesn't const provide block-level scoping too?

Comment: @MaryElliot Yes, but in these examples, `let`, `var`, and `const` will all provide the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the elements that match your query.

```
function hideAllButtons(button) {
  const buttonSelectors = ".play, .pause, .speaker"

  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelectors)

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
    hide(buttons[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like your example, under the selectors to get the selected buttons.

```
function hideAllButtons(button) {
  const buttonSelectors = ".play, .pause, .speaker";

  // Use the selectors to get all the buttons
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelectors);

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
    hide(buttons[i])
  }
}
```